# Get Stream Title from API

Tags: javascript, audio-player

I had a code that I was using with a API that is now been discontinued, and now, I need to update the JavaScript, to the new API. I want to get the stream title, and separate the artist and the song, to write them separatly.

This is the new API link: https://api.zeno.fm/mounts/metadata/subscribe/0emqj6gcjpzvv and this is the code that I was using (I've already changed the API link and didn't work).

```
<script>
    
    $var_streamesdg = document.getElementById("streamesdg");
    $var_icon = document.getElementById("playiconesdg");
    
    function playPause() {
    if (streamesdg.paused) {
        streamesdg.play()
        $var_icon.classList.remove('fa-play')
        $var_icon.classList.add('fa-pause')

    } else {
        streamesdg.pause()
        $var_icon.classList.remove('fa-pause')
        $var_icon.classList.add('fa-play')
        }
    }
    
    function stop() {
        streamesdg.pause();
        streamesdg.currentTime = 0;
    }

     
    function updateNowPlaying() {
        fetch('https://api.zeno.fm/mounts/metadata/subscribe/0emqj6gcjpzvv')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const currentSong = data.currentSong;
                const currentArtist = data.currentArtist;
                const elementArtist = document.getElementById('npArtist');
                const elementSong = document.getElementById('npSong');
                if (elementArtist, elementSong) {
                    elementArtist.textContent = `${currentArtist}`;
                    elementSong.textContent = `${currentSong}`;
                } else {
                    console.error('Element with id "npArtist" or "npSong" not found.');
                }

                // Add the fetch call for the itunes link inside the function
                fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${currentArtist}+${currentSong}&entity=song&limit=1`)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        if (data.resultCount === 0) {
                            console.log('No results found.');
                            document.getElementById('artwork').setAttribute('src', '    https://radioesdg.agr1beja.pt/wp-content/themes/radio_esdg/songartwork.png');
                        } else {
                            const artworkUrl = data.results[0].artworkUrl100;
                            document.getElementById('artwork').setAttribute('src', artworkUrl);
                            // Use the artworkUrl to display the artwork.
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching data from the API:', error);
            });
    }

    setInterval(updateNowPlaying, 5000);
    
    const express = require("express");
    const cors = require("cors");

    const corsOptions = {
      origin: "https://radioesdg.agr1beja.pt/",
    };

    const app = express();
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
</script>
```

I was thinking that just by changing the API link, it would work, but I think I need to change the variables names, but I don't know the new ones.

Comment: When I go to that URL, the response isn't JSON. It's also using server push, so it doesn't close the connection, and I'm not how you process that with the Fetch API.

Comment: Is their documentation available anywhere? Googling about gave back very little, and playing around with the link you provided (omitting parts of it, seeing what comes out, etc) didn't give enough info to do anything useful. If you don't mind alternatives: https://jonasrmichel.github.io/radio-garden-openapi/ . If, on the other hand, you want to use zeno.fm, please provide some info about the documentation.

Comment: @FiddlingAway I've already contacted the Zeno.FM and they said that they don't have a documentation

Comment: If using zeno.fm isn't an absolute must, you could give this a try: https://jonasrmichel.github.io/radio-garden-openapi/

Comment: @FiddlingAway if I use the gardin open api could you help me with that?

Comment: Looking again at your requirements and what Radio Garden API offers, it seems that RadioGarden API would, unfortunately, not be suitable - there isn't an endpoint which would offer the Now playing functionality. Going back to your Zeno.fm link - one thing you could do is to capture the response [like this](https://onlinephp.io/c/ac434). However, this requires you to have a server running PHP. Then, you would adapt your JS code to target your PHP script, and parse the response you get from it.